# setting location.href twice in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, location, href

I'm using

```
location.href=document.getElementById("link1").href;
location.href=document.getElementById("link2").href;
```

to run the scripts associated to the links:

```
<a id="link1" href="javascript:...">
<a id="link2" href="javascript:...">
```

The code works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome only the last location.href command (and so only the second piece of javascript code) is executed. How can I force it to execute both the first time and the second one?

Comment: What's actually *in* the `href` attributes? Since it's prefixed with `javascript:` have you checked that there's no errors in the contained JS? Also, use a click-handler; it's cleaner and easier.

Comment: HUH? You are calling two location.href calls? That is not going to work! It is a race condition. Learn about xmlhttprequest object! yikes.

Comment: Pages I interact with are not mine. You can test with any page you know. an example: <html>
<body>
<a id="link1" href="javascript:alert('1');">link1</a>
<br/>
<a id="link1" href="javascript:alert('2');">link2</a>
</body>
</html>. I know click handler. But the above solution is better because it would allow me to use the same code both for FF and Chrome.

Comment: In FF i can set location.href even thousand of times.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. I solved it by using `setTimeout` function to delay the second one a bit and it works  fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your javascript code into functions.

You can then call those functions from the links when they are clicked, as well as anywhere else you need them.
This is a much more stable way of running code rather than with urls.

Comment: Would you mind posting your functions/actual code? There is no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it.  If it isn't working for the OP, it's because they aren't doing it correctly.  I agree with xthexder.  Post your code.

Comment: Pages I interact with are not mine. Anyhow, you can test by yourself with any page. An example:<html>
<body>
<a id="link1" href="javascript:alert('1');">link1</a>
<br/>
<a id="link1" href="javascript:alert('2');">link2</a>
</body>
</html>